# How to get checked id from checkbox and pass selected id in to url by query param and fetch in other component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular8

I have a table with multiple fields in the table,

And I want to use checkbox to select the rows.

```
name     Age      date
-----------------------
aaa      22       12-06-2019
bbb      23       13-06-2019
ccc      24       21-09-2019
```

Scenario:

1.select the rows using the checkbox

2.While selecting the i have to fetch the id of that row(each row have id)

3.And I want to pass the url as(http://url/1,2,3) where the 1,2,3 are the id's of multiple fields.

4.Then I have to print that values.

Questions:

1. How I fetch the id by selecting the checkbox?
2. How to print the selected rows using angular 8??

Can anybody help me??

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Actually I got stuck to get the single id  by selecting the row. If  I got that, I can pass the id with API. How I get that??

Comment: if you can add your code here or create a stackblitz it would help

Answer (score 3):

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b98yt3)

in Class file

data:

```
   list: any = [
        {id:1, 'name': 'aaa', 'age': 22, 'date': '12-06-2019'},
        {id:2, 'name': 'bbb', 'age': 23, 'date': '13-06-2019'},
        {id:3, 'name': 'ccc', 'age': 25, 'date': '21-09-2019'}
   ];
```

// Store selected id in array

```
checkedItems: any = [];
```

// function to handle when user check or uncheck in checkbox

```
 onChecked(item: any, event: any){
    let {checked, value} = event.target;
    if(checked) {
      this.checkedItems.push(value);
    } else {
      let index = this.checkedItems.indexOf(value);
      if (index !== -1) this.checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

To pass selected item to the query param

```
 this.router.navigate(['/other'], {relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { id: this.checkedItems.join() } });
```

Template file:

Iterate on list and generate a table with checkbox and bind `onChange` Event with its handler name `onChecked`

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            [value]="item.id" 
            (change)="onChecked(item, $event)">
        </td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.age}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ids in query params of URL.

```js
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

changeQuery() {
  this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { ... }});
}
```

**How I fetch the id by selecting the checkbox?**

You can use

```js
check(values, id){
  console.log(values.currentTarget.checked, id);
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let test of tests"  >
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="check($event, test.id)" [(ngModel)]="test.selected" > {{test.name}} - {{test.selected}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

**How to print the selected rows using angular 8??**

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of selectedRows">
  <lable>row.col1</lable>
  <lable>row.col2</lable>
</div>
```